# when i try to upload new build on app store getting itunes error 90046 for applink

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, firebase, app-store-connect

I am using **firebase dynamic link** when trying archive and upload to app store with new build getting error.

Associated domain is well set and enabled from capabilities in xcode.

Need help.

The error description is as follow:

**iTunes Store Operation Failed**

description length:15189238

**iTunes store Operation Failed**

**ERROR ITMS-90046: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlement.Your application signature contains code signing entitlement that are not supported on iOS. Specifically, value 'applinks://abcd.app.goog.gl/' for key 'com.apple.developer.associated-domains' in 'Payload/Myapp.app/Myapp' is not supported"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess `applinks://abcd.app.goog.gl` is wrong.
Might you try to change your configuration with `applinks:abcd.app.goog.gl` ?

[image: applinks:abcd.app.goog.gl]

Comment: Thnaks alot. Saved my day. From last 2 days was feeling headache. and mistake is what applink with "//" and extra space. :)

Answer (score 0):

You say that your associated domains are well set in `Project Settings -> Capabilities`. Are you sure then, that you have used correct certificate? I would check it again if it's a production environment cert.